# Does unity3d's 5 seconds' simulation correspond to 5 seconds in real-world?

Tags: unity, realtime

How is time modelled in unity? Is it same as the time in real-world?

Answer (score 2):

Unity's elapsed-time metrics, such as [`deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) and [`fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) are in actual real-world seconds.

However, it is possible to scale (or effectively pause) the underlying time metrics using [`timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html), at which point the values reported by Unity will be different than real time according to the scaling specified. Other metrics, such as [`realtimeSinceStartup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) are not affected by adjusting the time scale.